# Using google sheets Need to automatically save or create a new sheet when the master is opened

Tags: google-sheets

This is my 1st time using Google sheets, I have a Master sheet set up for people to use, but I don't want them to have a chance to change the master and I don't trust them to create a copy before using the sheet.

I want people to start out opening the master but have the name changed after they open it and before they have the chance to make any changes.

The name of the new sheet should be the name used in the Master but add to it the current date.

The new sheet can be added to the current workbook

I don't want this to happen again if they sheet being created is opened later to modify or view the new sheet

I'm open to alternatives

The Google sheets api is fine to use

Please include examples of code or pointers to samples that all ready work

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Found some code that started me down the right road, played with it until it did what I wanted.  Only problem is that when you use the Google Sheet app on phone does not execute the onOpen code.

```js
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  /**
   * Duplicate and rename Master spreadsheet invoking the makeCopy() function.
   * The onOpen() function is automatically run when the spreadsheet is opened.
   */
  function onOpen() {

    var entries = [{
      name: "Weekly Cashier Accounting",
      functionName: "duplicateTemplateSheet"
    }];
    ss.addMenu("New sheet", entries);
    var oldSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName("Master"));
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "PST", "MM-dd-yyyy");

    if (ss.getSheetByName(formattedDate) == null) {
      Logger.log("Does not exist");
      var newSheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
      newSheet.activate();
      ss.moveActiveSheet(2);
      newSheet.setName(formattedDate);
      ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheetByName(formattedDate));
    }
  };
```

Thanks for the help